# Scope of a let variable JavaScript

Tags: javascript, methods, this, let

Based on my knowledge of JavaScript and **let**, a variable defined with this keyword is available after it has been defined throughout an entire scope (not necessarily function execution context like **var**).

Quoting from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let

"Variables declared by let have their scope in the block for which they are defined, as well as in any contained sub-blocks."

It is also my understanding that directly within a method (member function), **this** refers to the object, but within all other functions, **this** refers to the global object.
Given this, I am confused by the result below:

```js
let a = 7;
let b = {
  a: 13,
  foo: function() {
    (function() {
      console.log(this.a);
    })();
  }
};

b.foo();
```

I would have expected the value *7*. Instead, I get *undefined* on Chrome. On Firefox it seems nothing is logged.

I get the same behaviour if I replace the IIFE with a call to a function defined only within foo. Can anyone clarify what has happened here? Is that IIFE not part of a contained sub-block?

Comment: `this` does not have an `a` value. If you want to access the `a` from the first line then  use `console.log(a);`

Comment: From the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let#Scoping_rules_2): "_At the top level of programs and functions, let, unlike var, does not create a property on the global object_" --> `window.a` was never created.

Comment: Thanks, Teemu, that would certainly explain it!!!

Comment: not trying to thread jack but even when switching the let to a var it comes back undefined, why?

Comment: @AustinBentley: it comes back as 7 for me if I replace the 'let a = 7;' with 'var a = 7;' Did you maybe change the 'let' to 'var' for b instead? I can see that maybe having no effect.

Comment: when you use this inside of nested function 'this' keyword more likely will loose reference to the object that it is inside of... and in this situation 'this' is reference to the GLOBAL OBJECT .to solve this before the IIFE you have to write 'var self = this;' and replace 'console.log(this.a);' with 'console.log(self.a);'

Comment: i was using js fiddle and it wasn't working so i'm just going to attribute my problem to js fiddle

Comment: @AustinBentley Please don't blame jsFiddle, `var` works as described in a fiddle too, but you've to set Load Type to head/body instead of onload/DOM ready, to really declare the variable in the global scope.

Comment: @teemu. I wasnt blaming as much as attributing the area where my problem was from. Thank you for the tip!